# Pythonでlistのsortでkeyの設定が理解できません

Tags: python

以下のコードで**dic.sort(key=lambda dic: dic[1])** のlamda関数の意味が分からないでいます。
dic[1]はリストdicの２番目の要素だと思います。つまり、(2,'Nakao')だと思います。
しかし、タプルをキーにソートするというのが分かりません。
実際にコードを実行すると名前を元にソートしているようです。
理解できずに困っています。
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

```
dive_into_code = [(1, 'Noro'), (2, 'Nakao'), (3, 'Miyaoka'), (4, 'Kimura')]
dic = dive_into_code
dic.sort(key=lambda dic: dic[1])

print(dic)
```

Comment: 変数名が同じなので混同されているのかと思いますが、`dic = dive_into_code` の `dic` 変数と `lambda dic: dic[1]` の `dic` 変数(lambda 式のパラメータ)は全く別の変数(インスタンス)です。例えば `dic.sort(key=lambda d: d[1])` と書き直してみても結果は同じになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dic[1]はリストdicの２番目の要素だと思います。つまり、(2,'Nakao')だと思います。

そうではなく、`dic.sort(key=lambda dic: dic[1])`において`lambda dic`の`dic`は`dic.sort`の`dic`の各要素（リストの各要素）を表しています。つまり、`key=lambda dic: dic[1]`の`dic[1]`は'Noro', 'Nakao', 'Miyaoka', 'Kimura'を指します。なので質問のコードは名前のアルファベット順に並べ替えられます。

質問のコードでは`dic`が複数使われていて分かりにくくなっているので、下記の様に書いてみると分かりやすくなるかと思います。

```
dive_into_code = [(1, 'Noro'), (2, 'Nakao'), (3, 'Miyaoka'), (4, 'Kimura')]
dive_into_code.sort(key=lambda name: name[1])

print(dive_into_code)
# [(4, 'Kimura'), (3, 'Miyaoka'), (2, 'Nakao'), (1, 'Noro')]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。もう少し教えていただければ幸いです。lambda式の引数にタプルが入るのがイマイチ理解できませんでした。説明いただいた例ではnameにリスト要素であるタプルがセットされるようですが、ここが理解できずにいます。

Comment: 対象のリスト（今回はdive_into_code）の各要素がlambda式の引数になるということです。今回の例ではタプルとなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。承知いたしました。